# How do I solve "The iterator of this Seq is already in use"?

Tags: raku

This code:

```
sub MAIN(Int $N = 128)
{
    my @pascal = ((1,), { (0, |@^a) Z+ (|@^a, 0) } ... *);

    my @top = @pascal[^$N];
    say "Percentage of odd numbers in the first $N rows: ",
        (100 × @top».grep(* % 2).sum / @top.sum).fmt('%.12f%%');
}
```

gives me an error:

```
The iterator of this Seq is already in use/consumed by another Seq
(you might solve this by adding .cache on usages of the Seq, or
by assigning the Seq into an array)
  in sub MAIN at ./pascal1 line 8
  in block <unit> at ./pascal1 line 1
```

Any idea how to solve it?  I've tried adding `.cache` in several places, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The block you have as part of your sequence is creating a Seq. You should be able to cache it like this:

`{ ( (0, |@^a) Z+ (|@^a, 0) ).cache }`

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  (That was the one place I hadn't tried adding a `.cache`.  )

Comment: Guess we need some special code to handle `Seq` as part of a `...` sequence.

Answer (score 6):

`Z` returns a `Seq`

As a `Seq` produces it's next value, it throws the previous one away.

So you can generally only get the values from a `Seq` once.

The block `{…}` you have works by looking at the previous `Seq` it generated. So there is an issue. Either you get to see what is in those `Seq`, or the `...` operator gets to see what is in the `Seq`

---

The thing is, you probably didn't want the result of `Z` to be a `Seq`, you wanted it to be a `List`.

After all you start off the `...` sequence generator with a `List` `(1,)`.

```raku
((1,), { ((0, |@^a) Z+ (|@^a, 0)).List } ... *)
```